# _fullpath vs GetFullPathName

Tags: c, winapi

What is the difference between: _fullpath and GetFullPathName

Of course I mean compare their ANSI/Unicode variants  separatly

- Ansi: `_fullpath` vs `GetFullPathNameA`
- Uni: `_wfullpath` vs `GetFullPathNameW`

It seems that _fullpath has much nicer and simpler API as it allows
to allocate the buffer for you but I just think if I replace `GetFullPathNameW` with `_wfullpath` what would I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't necessary miss anything. In fact, it's quite possible that `_fullpath()` calls `GetFullPathName()`. In that case, `_fullpath()` works like a sort of wrapper for `GetFullPathName()`, which would explain why the interface seems a little simpler and easier to use.

You simply have multiple ways to accomplish the same task. And, as long as either method is not obsolete and performs the task needed, the choice is entirely up to you.

Answer (score -2):

`_fullpath` is part of the C library.
`GetFullPathName` is a Win32 API.

So basically, `_fullpath` is cross platform and `GetFullPathName` is Windows-specific.

In such cases, the C function usually relies on the underlying OS. So, in a Windows program, `_fullpath` most likely boils down to `GetFullPathName()`. But you don't have to care really.

Comment: `_fullpath` is not cross platform. It is not avalible on POSIX platforms, actually it is windows specific. The POSIX similar call is `realpath` and it does more then that.